# Spring Boot 2.2.0 syncBody deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In ServerResponse, syncBody has been deprecated.

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Mono<ServerResponse> syncBody(Object var1);
```

What should I do to replace this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If found the answer, at [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestBodySpec.html)

We should use `bodyValue` in `ServerResponse`